# What is the name of the art style in fallout 1 & 2?

Tags: fallout-2

Fallout 1 & 2 have this really fantastic art style. I wonder if anyone knows what it's called, and if there are other games that use it? Maybe someone can pinpoint what it is that makes this art style so unique?

[image]

It's a sort of pixel art, but it doesn't *feel* like pixel art if that makes sense.

Comment: It *is* pixel art though... Is there a specific property about the art that you're referring to?  The [isometric angle](http://www.technologystudent.com/prddes1/drawtec2.html), perhaps?  Or something about the colour palette?

Comment: I suppose it's something about the colour palette. Also, it seems to be a kind of "high-res" pixel art. Maybe there's no answer to this question?

Comment: I think one reason it looks _so beautiful_ is because it looks like it uses bump maps (textures that tell light how to interact with its base texture). Being pixel art I'm sure it doesn't (maybe it did with the 3D models (as mentioned by Miles Turin), I wouldn't think they had the technology for it), but you can see the detail of rust and tiny bumps in the shipping container, the car and even the ground and UI.

Comment: Don't underestimate the amount of effort they were willing to put into the pixel art.  The fact that 3D, changing camera angles and dynamic shadows weren't *a thing* back then also meant there was only one angle to draw from, and a talented artist could easily draw something like this by hand, light sources and shading included.  I agree that it is beautiful, by the way.  Maybe that's the thing that catches the OP's attention: the fact that it's *hand-drawn* in such detail, something which most pixel art games these days don't take the time for since it's considered "old" and "retro" anyway.

Comment: The first thing i see is the harsh light, rustic color palette and heavy use of metallic textures. Of course Fallout is more than that. The assets shown here are in sync with the in-game history, tech level and overall mood.